# Prove $|\sin(n)|$ or $|\sin(n + 1)|$ > $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that either $|\sin(n)|$ or $|\sin(n + 1)|$ > $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$.

It makes sense to me if I look at the graph of $|\sin x|$. The interval from $k\pi$ to $k\pi+\pi/2$ contains 2 integers. I think if one of them is less than $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$, the other one must be greater than $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$. However, I would like to make it rigorously.

Can we use other technique to prove it? I tried using contradiction (assume both $|\sin(n)|$ and $|\sin(n + 1)|$ < $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$), but I was stuck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Graphing it is a good way to go: focus on the interval $[0,\pi]$, as the graph of $|\sin(x)|$ is $\pi$-periodic. Now look at the regions $A=[0,1/2]$, $B=[1/2,\pi-1/2]$, and $C=[\pi-1/2,\pi]$. The region that will lead to a value less than or equal to $\sin(1/2)$ is $A\cup C$, which has length $\ell(A\cup C)=1$, which can only contain two consecutive integers in the most extreme case: when one is $k\pi-1/2$ and the other $k\pi+1/2$ (for some integer $k$). But since $\pi$ is irrational, it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove this by contradiction: Suppose that neither $|\sin(n)|$ nor $|\sin(n + 1)|$ > $\sin(\frac{1}{2})$, that is to say, suppose that,

$$|\sin{n}| \leq \sin{\frac12} \land |\sin{(n+1)}| \leq \sin{\frac12},$$

where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Squaring the two inequalities and adding them together,

$$\sin^2{n} + \sin^2{(n+1)} \leq 2\sin^2{\frac12}.$$

An equivalent form of the above inequality is:

$$\sin^2{n} + \sin^2{(n+1)} \leq 2\sin^2{\frac12} \iff 2\cos{(1)}\sin^2{(n+\frac12)} \leq 0\\
\implies \sin^2{(n+\frac12)} \leq 0.$$

Since the square of a real number can't be strictly less than zero, the way the inequality $\sin^2{(n+\frac12)} \leq 0$ can be true is if we have equality, i.e., if

$$\sin^2{(n+\frac12)} = 0 \iff \sin{(n+\frac12)} = 0\\
\iff n=k \pi - \frac12,~~~\text{where }k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

This contradicts are initial assumption $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. It took me a while to derive $2\cos(1)\sin^2(n+\frac{1}{2}) \leq 0$, but I finally did it.

Comment: How do you know that $\pi$ is not a rational number of the form $2n+1\over2k$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Because [$\pi$ is an irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational).

Comment: @DavidH, I just thought that it should be made explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I will solve the base case rest of argument is similiar.

**Claim:** If $0\leq sin(x) \leq sin(\dfrac{1}{2})$ then $sin(x+1)\geq sin(\dfrac{1}{2})$ 
where $x\in [0,\pi/2]$

from above constraction we can say that $0\leq x \leq 1/2$

Now, think the unit circle, since $x$ is radian it is equal the corresponding length on circle and $\pi$ is the half of the circle.

**case** $1$:If $x+1\leq 1/2$

Since $\pi/4\leq1$, $x+1\geq\pi/6$ we are done.

**case** $2$: Else:

Now, think the corresponding piece with the length $x+1$.

The remaning length $\pi-x-1\geq \pi-3/2 \geq1/2$.

Since the remainig length is bigger, $sin(x+1)\ge sin(1/2)$ as they are $y$ values of this points.

**Note:** My solution use geometric arguments and and @David 's solution is better.

Comment: Both solutions are great.